Vaadin Flow 24 controll AppLayout animation
In Vaadin Flow 24, there is a visual effect--animation--where upon initial page load, the main content in the AppLayout seems to slide into place from the top-left corner of the screen.
Is it possible to control this effect and, for example, disable it?

did you try     :    appLayout.getElement().setAttribute("style", "--vaadin-app-layout-transition: none");  ?

Thannk you! It is working now with vaadin-app-layout {   --vaadin-app-layout-transition: none; }

good to know ! can you accept the annswer so we can close the question

it is possible to control and disable this animation effect. Here's how you can do it:
Solution 1 : Java
 AppLayout appLayout = new AppLayout();
 appLayout.getElement().getStyle().set("--vaadin-app-layout-transition", 
 "none");

Solution 2 : CSS
 vaadin-app-layout {
    --vaadin-app-layout-transition: none;
}

don't forget to add the inline style to your view :
 @CssImport("./styles/my-view-styles.css")

